# Pointer values to normal values

Tags: go

I'm working on the below program. It all works without error but the values returned from the function are pointer values. If I remove the * and the &, the function does not run.

How would I revert a pointer back to a normal value at the end of that function?

```
converter := func(x int) *string {
    y := x*2
    result := string(y)
    return &result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `*` and `&` *does work* but isn't doing what you think it is.

`string` is a `type`, not a function!

In order to convert an `int` to `string`, you need to use `strconv.Itoa`. You can see the docs at https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/.

```
converter := func(x int) string {
    y := x*2
    return strconv.Itoa(y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

I've done that but get this erorr 'apply1 (int.Apply1: cannot apply type (func(int) string)(0x561bf0) to column)' - any idea?

Comment: From look at the [qframe code](https://github.com/tobgu/qframe/blob/16a94059f0f7c046206b68c5375e261267c5e731/function/int.go), it looks like it depends on a string pointer being returned. Try returning a pointer instead of the string object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It now works. But I don't understand, if I have put it back to *string and &y, just with the string conversion in the middle, why does it now work?

Comment: Because `string(2)` creates an empty `string` rather than converting `2` to `"2"`.

Comment: @JimWright  The  [string conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) `string(2)` evaluates to the UTF-8 representation of the rune 2 (`"\x02"`), not the empty string.